# find_or_create doesn't pass second condition to create

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

There are two entities here - facilities and agencies.  Each facility `belongs_to :agency`

I am writing the seed script for the database that reads CSV files and parses out data.

This should add facilities with their name and which agency they belong to:

```
Facility.joins(:agency)
.where(name: row[:name], agencies: { code: agency_code })
.first_or_create
```

I verified that the part up to `.where(name: row[:name], agencies: { code: agency_code })` does exactly what I want:

```
SELECT `facilities`.* FROM `facilities`
INNER JOIN `agencies` ON `agencies`.`id` = `facilities`.`agency_id`
WHERE `facilities`.`name` = 'Awesomesauce factory'
AND `agencies`.`code` = 'ROFL'
```

As you can see, a join is necessary because I am not hard-coding the IDs of the agencies and I need to know which one is `ROFL` in this case.

The agencies have already been inserted, so there is already an agency with the code `ROFL`.  My problem is that during the create step, the second condition in the WHERE clause isn't passed along:

```
INSERT INTO `facilities` (`agency_id`, `created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`)
VALUES (NULL, '2013-05-17 18:16:53', 'Awesomesauce Factory','2013-05-17 18:16:53')
```

See that NULL as the first value?  That's what I want to fix.  Right now I'm actually passing in a code block that sets it manually by performing a query for the agency that has that agency code but it seems like this should work without that hack using a subquery.  What I want to generate is:

```
INSERT INTO `facilities` (`agency_id`, `created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`)
VALUES (
(SELECT `agency_id` FROM `agencies` WHERE `code` = 'ROFL'),
'2013-05-17 18:16:53', 'Awesomesauce Factory','2013-05-17 18:16:53')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible because there's not a unique agency_id that satisfies your condition. `(SELECT 'agency_id' FROM 'agencies' WHERE 'code' = 'ROFL')` returns an array of records, whose length may or may not be 1.

In summary, this is not a limitation of the framework. It just cannot determine what the agency_id should be from the code you wrote.

Comment: The SQL that I wrote that I'm looking for is valid, and there is in fact a unique constraint on that column (I don't think Active Record is aware of this, though).  The SQL will break if there were to be more than one but that can't happen.  Is there a way to generate this SQL using Active Record or do I have to resort to two queries?